# get objects from an array based on objects hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, something like this:

```
let obj = [
  { name: "Qwerty1", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty2", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty3", status: "Staging" },
  { name: "Qwerty4", status: "Production" },
  { name: "Qwerty5", status: "Production" }
]
```

I need to create a function

```
getList(status) {

}
```

I will pass a status for this function eg: "Development" or "Stating" or "Production"

now, if I pass "Production" to this function, it should return an array of all the objects that has status: "Production" and all the objects that has status "Staging" and "Development"

if I pass the status "Staging", it should return an array of all the objects that has status "Staging" and all the objects that has status "Development"

and if I pass "Development", it should return an array of only the objects that has status "Development"

so the order is Production -> Staging -> Development ("Production" includes "Staging", "Staging" includes "Development");

please note that I can't change anything in this obj as it's coming from an API.

Comment: Are the `status` properties really `A`, `B`, `C`, ... in that order in the obj, or are those placeholders?

Comment: sorry, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list and check if object's `status` is equal or less than the `status` param. To assign numeric values to each status, create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of status -> value.

```js
const obj = [{"name":"Qwerty1","status":"Development"},{"name":"Qwerty2","status":"Development"},{"name":"Qwerty3","status":"Staging"},{"name":"Qwerty4","status":"Production"},{"name":"Qwerty5","status":"Production"}]

const statusToValue = new Map([['Development', 0], ['Staging', 1], ['Production', 2]])

const getList = (status) => obj.filter(o => statusToValue.get(o.status) <= statusToValue.get(status))

console.log(getList('Development'))      
console.log(getList('Staging'))
console.log(getList('Production'))
```

Comment: yes, but for the letters A, B, C these are just examples, in reality I'm having "Prod", "Staging"  and "Development" for the status

Comment: @vindict if you have "Prod", "Staging", and "Development" for the status, what's the hierarchy? Please edit this into your question.

Comment: @vindict - As long as the status have an inherent numeric value, or you can assign one to them, you can use this method. See 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

Find the last index of a matching `Status`, then `slice` the array from 0 to that index:

```js
let obj = [
  { name: "Qwerty1", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty2", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty3", status: "Staging" },
  { name: "Qwerty4", status: "Production" },
  { name: "Qwerty5", status: "Production" }
]

function getList(status) {
  let lastIndex;
  for (let i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (obj[i].status === status) {
      lastIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (lastIndex === undefined) {
    return [];
  }
  return obj.slice(0, lastIndex + 1);
}
console.log(getList('Development'));
console.log(getList('Staging'));
console.log(getList('Production'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.filter()`

This code loops through `obj`, creates the order, and uses `.filter()` to check if the current item is below the parameter `status` in the hierarchy.

```js
let obj = [
  { name: "Qwerty1", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty2", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty3", status: "Staging" },
  { name: "Qwerty4", status: "Production" },
  { name: "Qwerty5", status: "Production" }
]
let order = [...new Set(obj.map(e => e.status))];

function getList(status) {
  const output = obj.filter(e => order.indexOf(status) >= order.indexOf(e.status));
  return output;
}

console.log(getList("Staging"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but explicit:

```
function getList(status) {
    if (status === 'C') {
        return obj
    }
    if (status === 'B') {
        return obj.filter(object => object.status === 'B' || object.status === 'A')
    }
    if (status === 'A') {
        return obj.filter(object => object.status === 'A')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object literals to translate the actual words into numerical values for the comparison. This allows you to have the order you need to for the status levels, irrespective of the alphabetical order of the status names.

```js
let statusLevels = {"Development": 0,  "Staging": 1, "Production": 2};

let obj = [
  { name: "Qwerty1", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty2", status: "Development" },
  { name: "Qwerty3", status: "Staging" },
  { name: "Qwerty4", status: "Production" },
  { name: "Qwerty5", status: "Production" }
];

function getStatusArr(itemStatus) {
  // compares the status as numerical values base on the object literal
 return  obj.filter(o => statusLevels[o.status] <= statusLevels[itemStatus]);
}

console.log(getStatusArr('Staging'))

//gives all levels up to and including "Staging"
//[
//  {
//    "name": "Qwerty1",
//    "status": "Development"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "Qwerty2",
//    "status": "Development"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "Qwerty3",
//    "status": "Staging"
//  }
//]
```